# MongoDB.Driver C# auto expire documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am inserting documents into a collection and have a field called ExpireWhen. I would like to automatically remove those documents when the date has expired. I tried looking around but was not able to find information using the mongo db driver for c# version 2.6.1

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
this.CacheItemRecords().Indexes.CreateOneAsync(
     Builders<CacheItemRecordEntry>.IndexKeys.Ascending(c => c.ExpireWhen),
     new CreateIndexOptions { ExpireAfter = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0) }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MongoDB document ,
TTL indexes are special single-field indexes that MongoDB can use to automatically remove documents from a collection after a certain amount of time or at a specific clock time.

Here is how, I made both the scenarios working:

```
public class MongoLogMessage
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("expiry")]
    public DateTime ExpireAt { get; set; }

}

var indexKeysDefinition = Builders<MongoLogMessage>.IndexKeys.Ascending("ExpireAt");
var indexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions { ExpireAfter = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0) };
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<MongoLogMessage>(indexKeysDefinition, indexOptions);

_mongoCollection.Indexes.CreateOne(indexModel);
```

1. If you want the document to be deleted at Specific clock time, you can set the ExpireAfter value for the generated index.
2. If you want the document to be deleted after certain amount of time, you can set the ExpireAt property value and set the ExpireAfter in IndexOptions as 0.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Link](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/c-driver-ttl-at-specific-time/112149/2) you create the index with the ttl the following way, so the document will be removed at the exact time by the indexed value:

```
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<MyEntity>(
    keys: Builders<MyEntity>.IndexKeys.Ascending("ExpireAt"),
    options: new CreateIndexOptions
    {
        ExpireAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
        Name = "ExpireAtIndex"
    });

_collection.Indexes.CreateOne(indexModel);
```

While the model should have the following property:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    // Other properties
    public DateTime ExpireAt { get; set; }
}
```

Example:

```
var entity = new MyEntity()
{
    // other properties
    ExpireAt = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(120)
};
```

By default the TTL background task runs every 60 second. So whenever the index matches with the criteria that ExpireAt is in the past, then the document will be removed automatically.